# Welcome to the Jungles of South America

Tags: riddle

I have another simple riddle for the community here at Puzzling.

> I am as furry as can be.
>
> I like scaling trees.
>
> Often referred to as leisurely.
>
> I enjoy life steadily.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a

> sloth?

I am as furry as can be.

> Sloths are furry

I like scaling trees.

> They live in trees

Often referred to as leisurely.

> Sloths are depicted as laidback

I enjoy my life steadily.

> They're slow and steady!

Title:

> Sloths live in the jungles of South America

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: Same here, what a coincidence!

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Sloth?

I am as furry as can be.

> Sloths have fur

I like scaling trees.

> They practically live on trees.

Often referred to as leisurely.

> People call each other sloths

I enjoy life steadily.

> They move slowly

Comment: Close one!! We're always on the same page!